# Wordpress do term is child of something term

Tags: wordpress, parent-child, taxonomy-terms

For example I have term 'child', how to check do this term is child of term 'Mother' ?

Comment: DNA test..oops....sorry but I am unable to get urs ..what exactly u want and how it is relevant to wordpress..post/category etc hierarchy or something else ur looking for ?

Comment: Yep herarchy, looking for function like `is_child()` ;D

Comment: Check this if this is what something you are looking for http://bavotasan.com/2009/check-if-a-page-is-a-child-of-another-page-in-wordpress/

Comment: Yes I looking for this, please write post, I will mark It as answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comments I think you can do this in the below mentioned manner -

Place this method in your theme `functions.php` file

```
function is_child($pageID) { 
    global $post; 
    if( is_page() && ($post->post_parent==$pageID) ) {
               return true;
    } else { 
               return false; 
    }
}
```

Then you can use this method anywhere in your theme --

```
<?php
if(is_child(343)) {
echo "This is a child page of 'The Parent Page Title'.";
}
?>
```

Reference -  http://bavotasan.com/2009/check-if-a-page-is-a-child-of-another-page-in-wordpress/